# Graph-like structures with Qtree

Tags: diagrams, qtree, tikz-qtree

The [Qtree](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/advice/latex/qtree/) package is "a LaTeX package for drawing **tree** diagrams." Is it possible to draw simple graph-like diagrams with it, similar to the one depicted below? If not, should I resort to [TikZ-qtree](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-qtree)?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible to do with `qtree`. (It is, after all `qtree` and not `qgraph` :-)) But it should be fairly easy to do in `tikz-qtree` I think. Since the basic syntax is the same, but `tikz-qtree` is much more powerful, I would start there.

Comment: @Alan: Thanks. Could you please help me with the `tikz-qtree` code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=1cm, every node/.style={font=\sffamily}]

\Tree [.PSPACE 
      [.PP  
        [.BQP 
            [.BPP  \edge[white]; {} \edge; \node[xshift=2cm] (P) {P}; ] ] 
            [.\node (NP) {NP}; ]]]
\draw (P.north) -- (NP.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

I've changed the method of moving the P node so that it is centred correctly. (Output image has been put in an `\fbox` to show the image edges.)

[image: output of code]

Comment: +1, thanks. There's one minor problem, though: although the `\edge[white];` command hides the edge, it prevents the diagram from correctly being centered on the page.

Comment: Removing `\phantom{\hspace{4cm}}` (leaving just empty braces) makes the positioning a whole lot better, though it's still very slightly off centre.

Comment: @Sadeq Jake's comment is right. I added the `\phantom` to centre the P relative to the PSPACE. You can remove it and add `[xshift=2cm]` to the P node.