# How to connect two parents to the same child, with parents not in the same tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, forest

I'm trying to draw a specific tree, with two parents node linked to the same child. The problem is that one of the parent is outside the main tree.

Here's the code I have for the moment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
%\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

%\begin{exe}
\begin{forest}
qtree edges/.style={for tree= parent anchor=north, child anchor=south}
   [A, grow=north
       [C, name=C, grow'=north
           [D, grow=north ]
           [E, name=t5, grow=north ]
       ]
       [B, grow=north ]
   ]
   \hspace{0.8cm}
   [$F$, name=F, grow=north ]
   %\draw (F.north) -- (C.south);
\end{forest}
%\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

I'd like the nodes F and C to be connected. I don't know why, but if I delete the dollar signs, node F doesn't even appear on my document.

Another thing is that I want the forest environment to be embedded in an example environment, but this doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various problems with your code.  First, multirooted structures are *not* formally trees, so you can't expect tree drawing packages to handle them directly.  See the following question for more discussion on techniques for this:

- [Multi-rooted Tree-like Structures and Nodes with Multiple Parents in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114109/2693)

Furthermore, the syntax for a `gb4e` example requires that the example be introduced by the `\ex` macro (within the `{exe}` environment.)

To handle the multidominance, I've used Ignasi's suggestion to create a node relative to the `-|` path between node A and E.  You could also use the TikZ `positioning` library, to manually place the node.  I've also removed the `tikz-qtree` package, since it's not needed if you're using `forest`.  Since your 'tree' grows upwards, I've added `baseline` to one of the terminal nodes so that it will align properly with the example number, and set the growth function globally for the tree.  Also, you had a particular style for nodes in your example, but you never applied that style, and I've done that too.

You should also load `gb4e` after most other packages, since it can cause problems otherwise.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\usepackage{gb4e}


\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{forest}
qtree edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=north, child anchor=south}},
for tree={grow=north},qtree edges
   [A, name=A,
       [C, name=C 
           [E,baseline,name=E  ]
           [D,   ]
       ]
       [B ]
   ] 
   \node  (F) at (A-|E) {F};
   \draw (F.north) -- (C.south);
   \end{forest}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: If you want to vertically align `F` with `E` (like `A` with `D`) you can use `\node (F) at (A-|t5) {F};`.

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks.  That's a good trick to know.

Comment: Another way to simulate multidominance (by a manual `\draw`) is to put all the nodes in the same tree and make the proper ones `phantom`, like in this simplified version of OP's example: `\begin{forest}[,phantom[A[B][C,name=C]][F,name=F]]\draw (F)--(C);\end{forest}`