# Multiply dominated nodes in the forest environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

[image]

**Edit:** I think I need to join two different trees (there's two root nodes). I'm at a loss.

---

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I need for the node that says A in the following graph to be dominated by two nodes and not only one (I need it to be a multiply dominated node; so I need to add another branch). Is this possible in the forest environment? How can I fix these?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{forest} 
  for tree={grow=0,l=3cm,anchor=east,child anchor=east,grow=west, s sep+=1pt}
    [{$(e_{i+1} \land e''_{j+n})$C$p$}
      [{$(e_i \land e'_2)$C$e_{i+1}$}
        [{$e_1$C$e_2$C$\dots$C$e_i$}]
        [{$((e'_1 \supset e'_2) \land e'_1)$C$e'_2$}
        [$(e'_1 \supset e'_2)$]
        [A]
        ]
      ]
      [{$(e''_j \land e'''_k)$C$e''_{j+1}$C...C$e''_{j+n}$}
        [{$e''_1$C$e''_2$C$\dots$C$e''_j$}]
        [{$e'''_1$C$e'''_2$C$\dots$C$e'''_k$}]
      ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114109/2693

Comment: Also related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146183/2693