# How to draw the physical tree with balls under both the stress of strings and gravity?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I want to draw the physical model of graph that has a ball for each vertex and a piece of string for each edge. In this model, if you lift a ball high enough, the other balls are pulled up along with it, affected by *both the stress of strings and gravity*. An illustration is shown in the following figure.

[image: physical-tree-balls-gravity]

However, using `tikz-qtree`, I can only draw an ordinary tree which cannot visualize the strings or gravity (*and is somewhat ugly*).

[image: physical-tree-balls]

Therefore, I want to know that

> How to draw the physical tree with balls under both the stress of strings and gravity?

---

My code using `tikz-qtree` is as follows.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw, circle] (r) at (0,0) {$r$};
  \node [draw, circle, blue, very thick] (s) at (2,0) {$s$};
  \node [draw, circle] (t) at (4,0) {$t$};
  \node [draw, circle] (u) at (6,0) {$u$};

  \node [draw, circle] (v) at (0,-2) {$v$};
  \node [draw, circle] (w) at (2,-2) {$w$};
  \node [draw, circle] (x) at (4,-2) {$x$};
  \node [draw, circle] (y) at (6,-2) {$y$};

  \draw (r) to (v);
  \draw (r) to (s);
  \draw (s) to (w);
  \draw (t) to (u);
  \draw (t) to (w);
  \draw (t) to (x);
  \draw (u) to (x);
  \draw (u) to (y);
  \draw (x) to (y);
  \draw (y) to (u);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \tikzset{level distance = 36pt, sibling distance = 25pt}
  \tikzset{every node/.style = {draw, circle}}

  \Tree [.\node[blue, very thick](s){$s$}; 
            [.$r$ $v$ ]
            [.\node(w){$w$}; 
                [.\node(t){$t$}; \node(u){$u$}; ] 
                [.\node(x){$x$}; \node(y){$y$}; ]
            ] 
        ]

  % cross edges
  \draw [dashed, thick, red] (t) to [out = -45, in = 225] (x);
  \draw [dashed, thick, red] (u) to [out = -45, in = 225] (y);
  \draw [dotted, thick, purple] (x.-110) to (u);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to check out the `tkz-graph` package. Documentation in French, but with lots of examples to play with.  It doesn't do exactly what you want, but it is designed for graphs and not trees; anything you do with `tikz-qtree` will likely be very hacky, since it's not designed for that. See also [Multi-rooted Tree-like Structures and Nodes with Multiple Parents in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114109).

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks. It seems more suitable for my purpose. I will check it carefully later. The hardest part (IMO) is to determine the positions of the balls under gravity.

Comment: I don't get the question exactly. Do you want to know how to draw those bent lines connecting the nodes? If yes, I have an answer.

Comment: @HarishKumar "Bent lines connecting nodes" is one aspect. The other aspect is how to put the balls in a common subtree at the same layer closely next to each other (due to strings and gravity).

Comment: The new version of TikZ 3.00 has electrical charge and spring tension properties for the placement of graph elements.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some examples with the graph drawing stuff from the latest PGF version. I'm not quite sure about the best way to define new edges but at least the method I used seems to work. It requires `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{topaths,graphs,graphdrawing,decorations}
\usegdlibrary{layered,trees}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{squiggle}{draw}{
\state{draw}[width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength]{
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{0.25*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{0.25*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}}%
    {\pgfpoint{0.75*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{-0.25*\pgfdecoratedpathlength}}%
    {\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{0pt}}
}}

\tikzgraphsset{
 edge squiggle/.style={
   new --/.code n args={4}{
    \path [-, every new --/.try]
      (##1\tikzgraphleftanchor)
      edge[##3, decoration=squiggle, decorate] ##4
      (##2\tikzgraphrightanchor);}
  },
  edge loop/.style={
   new --/.code n args={4}{
    \draw [-, every new --/.try]
     (##1)
      edge [out=260, in=280, looseness=3] ##4
       (##2);}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\tikz\graph [nodes={shape=circle, fill=gray!50}, edge squiggle, 
  chain shift=(0:2cm), group shift=(270:2cm)]{
  E -- S -- A;
  D -!- C -- B;
  D -- E; D -- S;
  C -- S; B -- A; 
};

\hskip1cm

\tikz\graph [layered layout, nodes={shape=circle, fill=gray!50},
  level distance=1.5cm] {
  S -- {A -- B, C -- B, E, D};
  {[edge loop] E -- D};
  {[same layer] A, C, D, E};
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I suppose the second row of nodes in the graph on the right should have no space between them.