# phonological structures

Tags: pstricks, linguistics, pst-asr

I need to do this:

[image]

Apologies for the non-digital reference. :)

My attempt with `pst-asr` is the following. I can't figure out what it wrong with it. Can someone help?

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-asr,graphicx}
\newpsstyle{bigsyls}{extragap=.6ex,unitxgap=true,xgap=3.5ex,ts=0p ($\times$),sy=5.5ex ($\sigma$) .7ex,ph=-4.5ex (pf)}
\newpsstyle{dashed}{linestyle=dashed,dash=3pt 2pt}
\newpsstyle{crossing}{xed=true,xedtype=\xedcirc,style=dashed}
\newpsstyle{dotted}{linestyle=dotted,linewidth=1.2pt,dotsep=1.6pt}
\def\feat#1{$\rm [#1]$}
\def\crossing{\pscircle[linestyle=solid,linewidth=.5pt](0,0){.7ex}}%
\newdimen\dimpuba
\newdimen\dimpubb
\def\TO{\quad$\rightarrow$\quad}
\tiershortcuts

\begin{document}

\newtier{dorsal, high, back, low}
\psset{xgap=1.5in, yunit=3em, ts=0 (Pg), sy=1 ((),
 dorsal=-1 (Dg), high=-2 ([), back=-2.6 ([),
 low=-3.2 ([), sysym=\feat{-cons}, tssym=Place}
\DefList{\dorsalA{0}, \dorsalB{1}, \highoffsetA{-.3}, \highoffsetB{.8},%
\lowoffsetA{0}, \lowoffsetB{1}, \backoffsetA{.3}, \backoffsetB{1.3} }

\asr \X \X |
 \@(\dorsalA,dorsal){Dorsal}
    \-(0,ts)
 \@(\dorsalB,dorsal){Dorsal}
    \-(1,ts)
 \@[\highoffsetA](\dorsalA,high){\feat{$\alpha$high}}
    \-(\dorsalA,dorsal)
    \-[xed=true](\dorsalA,dorsal)
 \@[\lowoffsetA](\dorsalA,low){\feat{$\beta$low}}
    \-(\dorsalA,dorsal)
    \-[xed=true](\dorsalA,dorsal)
 \@[\backoffsetA](\dorsalA,back){\feat{$\gamma$back}}
    \-(\dorsalA, dorsal)    
    \-[style=dotted](\dorsalB, dorsal)
 \@[\highoffsetB](\dorsalB,high){\feat{-$\alpha$high}}
    \-(\dorsalB,dorsal)
    \-[style=dotted](\dorsalA,dorsal)
 \@[\lowoffsetB](\dorsalB,low){\feat{-$\beta$low}}
    \-(\dorsalB, dorsal)
    \-[style=dotted](\dorsalA,dorsal)
 \@[\backoffsetB](\dorsalB,back){\feat{-$\gamma$back}}
    \-(\dorsalB, dorsal)    
    \-[xed=true](\dorsalB,dorsal)
 \endasr

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Remember that `pst-asr` requires compilation with `latex+dvips` not `pdflatex` but your first line is telling it to use the latter.

Comment: Oh - can you remind me the right code to do that?

Comment: Change `% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex` to `% !TEX TS-program = latex`.

Comment: ok, great. I changed the code above. The problem is still there, unfortunately.

Comment: One problem is the definition of `\feat`. `\feat{$\alpha$high}` expands to `$\rm [$\alpha$high]$`, where \alpha is typeset outside of math mode. This results in the message `Missing $ inserted`.  Define `\feat` simply as `\def\feat#1{[#1]}`, or better as `\newcommand\feat[1]{[#1]}`. Then LaTeX can process a few lines more,  but then another error occurs.

Comment: @gernot Actually in this case it's probably better to remove the `$` from inside the argument. This ensures that the `-` and `+` (which will also typically be present) are set in math mode.  Of course you could also do `\feat{$-$voice}` as well, but for input simplicity it makes sense in this case to leave math mode in the macro definition.

Answer (score 7):

First off, `pst-asr` documents require `latex+dvips` for compilation, and cannot be processed with `pdflatex`.  The line:

```
 % !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
```

needs to be changed to

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex.
```

Second, the definition of `\feat` wraps the content in math mode, which means you can't embed math code inside it, so as a result:

```
\feat{-$\alpha$high}
```

fails. Unfortunately the error, `Missing $ inserted` is ironically very unhelpful, since the problem is (from your perspective) in fact extra `$` signs, not missing ones.  Of course the error does in fact make sense, as Gernot remarks in the comment, since `\feat{-$\alpha$high}` expands to `$\rm -$\alpha$high$` yielding two math mode expressions with an `\alpha` in the middle, and as a result the `\alpha` ends up *not* being in math mode at all, hence the missing `$` error.

So instead of the line above you need simply:

```
\feat{-\alpha high}
```

Finally, for reasons I don't really understand (because I never use the package) `pst-asr` seems to be very sensitive to  spaces within its commands. For example:

```
  \-(\dorsalA, dorsal)
```

fails, while

```
 \-(\dorsalA,dorsal)
```

works.  Removing these extra spaces, the document now compiles. The output isn't quite like your picture, but I assume you can figure out how to fix that yourself now that you have working code.

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-asr,graphicx}
\newpsstyle{bigsyls}{extragap=.6ex,unitxgap=true,xgap=3.5ex,ts=0p ($\times$),sy=5.5ex ($\sigma$) .7ex,ph=-4.5ex (pf)}
\newpsstyle{dashed}{linestyle=dashed,dash=3pt 2pt}
\newpsstyle{crossing}{xed=true,xedtype=\xedcirc,style=dashed}
\newpsstyle{dotted}{linestyle=dotted,linewidth=1.2pt,dotsep=1.6pt}
\def\feat#1{$\rm [#1]$} % 
% Since this macro is already in mathmode you don't need $...$ inside its arguments
% i.e., instead of \feat{$\alpha$ voice} use \feat{\alpha voice}

\def\crossing{\pscircle[linestyle=solid,linewidth=.5pt](0,0){.7ex}}%
\newdimen\dimpuba
\newdimen\dimpubb
\def\TO{\quad$\rightarrow$\quad}
\tiershortcuts

\begin{document}

\newtier{dorsal, high, back, low}
\psset{xgap=1.5in, yunit=3em, ts=0 (Pg), sy=1 ((),
 dorsal=-1 (Dg), high=-2 ([), back=-2.6 ([),
 low=-3.2 ([), sysym=\feat{-cons}, tssym=Place}
\DefList{\dorsalA{0}, \dorsalB{1}, \highoffsetA{-.3}, \highoffsetB{.8},%
\lowoffsetA{0}, \lowoffsetB{1}, \backoffsetA{.3}, \backoffsetB{1.3} }

\asr \X \X |
 \@(\dorsalA,dorsal){Dorsal}
    \-(0,ts)
 \@(\dorsalB,dorsal){Dorsal}
    \-(1,ts)
 \@[\highoffsetA](\dorsalA,high){\feat{\alpha high}}
    \-(\dorsalA,dorsal)
    \-[xed=true](\dorsalA,dorsal)
 \@[\lowoffsetA](\dorsalA,low){\feat{\beta low}}
    \-(\dorsalA,dorsal)
    \-[xed=true](\dorsalA,dorsal)
 \@[\backoffsetA](\dorsalA,back){\feat{\gamma back}}
    \-(\dorsalA,dorsal) 
    \-[style=dotted](\dorsalB,dorsal)
 \@[\highoffsetB](\dorsalB,high){\feat{-\alpha high}}
    \-(\dorsalB,dorsal)
    \-[style=dotted](\dorsalA,dorsal)
 \@[\lowoffsetB](\dorsalB,low){\feat{-\beta low}}
    \-(\dorsalB,dorsal)
    \-[style=dotted](\dorsalA,dorsal)
 \@[\backoffsetB](\dorsalB,back){\feat{-\gamma back}}
    \-(\dorsalB,dorsal)    
    \-[xed=true](\dorsalB,dorsal)
 \endasr

 \end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: It would be better to use `\newcommand*` than `\def`, though, wouldn't it?

Comment: @cfr Yes, but the commands are being taken verbatim from the `pst-asr` docs, since John Frampton, the author is a plain TeX user. So in the general case yes, but in this case, it's probably safer (in the short run) to keep the macros as they are. Do we have a question about converting plain TeX macros to LaTeX macros I could link to?

Comment: I was really following up your comment on the question which seemed to address gernot's maths point but not the TeX -> LaTeX point. I don't know if we have a question about conversion. I don't remember one, but it seems as if there should be one somewhere ...?

Comment: @cfr Yes, I understand, but I'm a bit afraid to imply what might appear (to a beginner) to be a 'general rule' for conversion, since no such rule can actually exist, especially given the existence of delimited macros in TeX.

Comment: What a stupid mistake! Thank you, @AlanMunn, for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution for creating autosegmental diagrams using the great [`forest` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest?lang=en).

There are two styles in the `\forestset` block: the `asr` style makes edges leave from the parent’s `south` anchor and also sets the tree packing dimensions, and `strike` adds a double strike-through (`╪`) to an edge.

I created a phantom (invisible) root node (`R`) whose children are the two `[–cons]` nodes, to simulate two separate trees. I then drew the main nodes of each tree and used the `strike` style on the relevant edges. To create the [“multi-dominance” effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114329/46230), I manually drew dashed lines from the other parent’s `south` nodes to the named leaves.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\forestset{
asr/.style={
  for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
%   child anchor=north,
    s sep=4mm,
    l sep=6mm
  }
},
strike/.style={
  edge label={
    node[midway, sloped, rotate=90] {=}
  }
}
}

\begin{forest}asr
[R,phantom
  [{[–cons]}
    [Place
      [Dorsal
        [{[α high]},strike]
        [{[β low]},strike]
        [{[γ back]},name=g1]
      ]
        { \draw[dashed] (.south) -- (a2); }
        { \draw[dashed] (.south) -- (b2); }
    ]
  ]
  [{[–cons]}
    [Place
      [Dorsal
        [{[α high]},name=a2]
        [{[β low]},name=b2]
        [{[γ back]},strike]
      ]
        { \draw[dashed] (.south) -- (g1); }
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run the document with xelatex (can be choosed from the menu):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-asr,graphicx}
\newpsstyle{bigsyls}{extragap=.6ex,unitxgap=true,xgap=3.5ex,
            ts=0p ($\times$),sy=5.5ex ($\sigma$) .7ex,ph=-4.5ex (pf)}
\newpsstyle{dashed}{linestyle=dashed,dash=3pt 2pt}
\newpsstyle{crossing}{xed=true,xedtype=\xedcirc,style=dashed}
\newpsstyle{dotted}{linestyle=dotted,linewidth=1.2pt,dotsep=1.6pt}
\def\feat#1{\rm [#1]}
\def\crossing{\pscircle[linestyle=solid,linewidth=.5pt](0,0){.7ex}}%
\newdimen\dimpuba
\newdimen\dimpubb
\def\TO{\quad$\rightarrow$\quad}
\tiershortcuts

\begin{document}

\newtier{dorsal, high, back, low}
\psset{xgap=1.5in, yunit=3em, ts=0 (Pg), sy=1 ((),
        dorsal=-1 (Dg), high=-2 ([), back=-2.6 ([),
        low=-3.2 ([), sysym=\feat{-cons}, tssym=Place}
\DefList{\dorsalA{0}, \dorsalB{1}, \highoffsetA{-.3}, \highoffsetB{.8},%
        \lowoffsetA{0}, \lowoffsetB{1}, \backoffsetA{.3}, \backoffsetB{1.3} }

\asr \X \X |
  \@(\dorsalA,dorsal){Dorsal}
    \-(0,ts)
  \@(\dorsalB,dorsal){Dorsal}
    \-(1,ts)
  \@[\highoffsetA](\dorsalA,high){\feat{$\alpha$high}}
    \-(\dorsalA,dorsal)
    \-[xed=true](\dorsalA,dorsal)
  \@[\lowoffsetA](\dorsalA,low){\feat{$\beta$low}}
    \-(\dorsalA,dorsal)
    \-[xed=true](\dorsalA,dorsal)
  \@[\backoffsetA](\dorsalA,back){\feat{$\gamma$back}}
    \-(\dorsalA,dorsal)    
    \-[style=dotted](\dorsalB,dorsal)
  \@[\highoffsetB](\dorsalB,high){\feat{-$\alpha$high}}
    \-(\dorsalB,dorsal)
    \-[style=dotted](\dorsalA,dorsal)
  \@[\lowoffsetB](\dorsalB,low){\feat{-$\beta$low}}
    \-(\dorsalB,dorsal)
    \-[style=dotted](\dorsalA,dorsal)
  \@[\backoffsetB](\dorsalB,back){\feat{-$\gamma$back}}
    \-(\dorsalB,dorsal)    
    \-[xed=true](\dorsalB,dorsal)
\endasr

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the point of this answer, other than to show that some `pstricks` code will run with `xelatex` too? Why not just add a comment to my answer?