# How to write this tree in Tex

Tags: tikz-trees, branching

I want to write this following picture in tex. I am new in drawing branching in tex. So I saw some examples **in this site**. But could not find this type.

### Again how to put dots in the end?

**A picture is given below:**

[image: Thanks]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114329/117534

Comment: @Troy thanks ... can you tell me how to write that in Mathstack. I can do that in Texmaker but but mathstack do not support **tkz-graph package**

Comment: MathJax is meant for equations, not for `tikz` or `pgfplots` graphics.

Comment: @MANMAID Not really.. Partially because I don't have much experience in MathJax, but also because such questions are not really on-topic here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3483/117534.

Comment: @HenriMenke thanks but how about the dots in the end of the tree!

Comment: @Troy I when I was compiling I found that there are dots in the end of the tree. That is not given in that post. Can you help me here?

Comment: @MANMAID Can you post the code that you have now as a [compilable example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we don't have to start from scratch?

Comment: Not really a duplicate of the linked question because the diagram is not actually a tree ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this, adapted from [Alan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114329/117534):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\renewcommand*{\EdgeLineWidth}{0.25pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-0.3cm]
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Empty]
    \Vertex{A}
    \Vertex[x=-0.5,y=-1]{B}
    \Vertex[x=0.5, y=-1]{C}
    \Vertex[x=0, y=-2]{D}
    \Vertex[x=-1, y=-2]{E}
    \Vertex[x=1, y=-2]{F}
    \Vertex[x=-1.5, y=-3]{G}
    \Vertex[x=-0.5, y=-3]{H}
    \Vertex[x=0.5, y=-3]{I}
    \Vertex[x=1.5, y=-3]{J}
    \Edges(B,A,C)
    \Edges(E,B,D,C,F)
    \Edges(G,E,H,D,I,F,J)
    \node[below=of G] (dG) {$\vdots$};
    \node[below=of H] (dH) {$\vdots$};
    \node[below=of I] (dI) {$\vdots$};
    \node[below=of J] (dJ) {$\vdots$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the whole thing is in a `tikzpicture` environment, adding dots is just a matter of adding some extra nodes, of which there are probably many different ways of doing so.

Comment: something is wrong, sir... it is taking too long time in both sharelatex and in TexMaker but yet not complied!

Comment: @MANMAID It's compiling fine for me (locally). Maybe its installing the required packages? I don't know about Sharelatex, as I'm too lazy to create an account, but it compiles well on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/qndgsssggnps

Comment: thanks a lot! Interesting fact ... overleaf worked! Although texmaker is complining for 1 hrs upto now... after installing package... thanks a lot!